# How to create custom endpoint which does not have primary id as required parameter

Tags: oracle-rest-data-services

In Oracle VBCS in a Business Object, I am creating an Object function that is exposed as a REST endpoint but it's making the primary id mandatory I want to have an endpoint that does not require the primary key.

I added a simple addUserDemo function but its endpoints were created like this.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to remove `{User_Id}` from the URL?

Comment: This is not an Oracle databases question and, as such, you do not want the [Oracle] tag. Please [edit] the question and add the correct tags (I've taken a guess that you want [Oracle Rest-Data-Services] but it could be [Oracle-BI])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object functions always work on a specific row in an object.
You can create a dummy object that has only one row and is marked as containing setup data - and have the function run on that one.
https://blogs.oracle.com/vbcs/post/service-methods-for-business-objects-in-visual-builder